# Find this ODE solution $xy''+2y'-xy=e^x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find this following ODE solution
$$xy''+2y'-xy=e^x$$

my try: since
$$xy''+y'+y'-xy=e^x$$
then
$$(xy')'-xy+y'=e^x$$
then I can't

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you were halfway there.
$$(xy)''=(xy'+y)'=xy''+2y'$$

Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

If you define $u = xy$, then $u^{\prime\prime} = xy^{\prime\prime}+2y^\prime$ and your equation becomes $u^{\prime\prime}-u = e^x$.

We now can solve for $u$, and then use $\displaystyle y=\frac{u}{x}$ to find $y$.

The solution of the homogeneous equation $u^{\prime\prime}-u = 0$ can be obtained by trying with $e^{\alpha x}$. If you plug this into the homogeneous equation, you will find that $\alpha^2 - 1 = 0$, so $\alpha=\pm1$. Threfore, $u_h(x) = A e^x + B e^{-x}$.

For the particular solution of the inhomogeneous equation $u^{\prime\prime}-u = e^x$, it's very reasonable to try with $u_p(x) = \kappa x e^x$. If you plug it into the equation you will find that $\kappa=\frac{1}{2}$, so the final solution is

$\displaystyle u_h(x) = A e^x + B e^{-x} + \frac{xe^x}{2}$.